# ndb.Query: only return items that is grandchild of other item

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a structure with `house` in `district` in `city` and I need to search for houses in a specified `city` and/or `district` using `ndb.Query` (since I also need to filter for other properties).

`City` has a list of `district`'s and `district` has a list of `house`'s.

Note: there are no ancestors here, since this is part of a bigger graph, so ancestor queries are not possible.

Example:
Get all `house`'s that have `area > 500` in a specified `city` (by a field `name` in `city`).

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot do JOINs, you would have to change your design a little bit.

The easiest option is to add `city_name` as a property for `House`, that seems to answer your example and general question.

If you can't change the model, or your queries are more complex, you could have another entity holding all the information you need for queries (your denormalization table), and use it only for that. `House` can be its ancestor and so you can do key only queries, which will save you time/money. Also try to [define indexes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/indexconfig) for your most common queries.